# Undirected random graph generation

Tags: java, graphics

I would like to generate a complete(all node is connected) undirected graph. I have got two algorethmical solutions for this problem, the Poisson disc sampling and Delaunay triangulation.

I have found an efficient code solution for Delaunay triangulation, but there are some errors in the import section:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/8872240/

I have also another one that uses Poisson disc sampling, but it generates also unconnected nodes. (Are there some possible solutions with appropriate parameterization?)
http://paste.ubuntu.com/8872273/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kovacs, there happens to exist another Stack Exchange site simply called Programmers.

Comment: It is quite unclear what you want to achieve. Should there be an edge between any two nodes or just a path? Do you need a triangulation?

Comment: @Henry: I have made two pictures as examples. This is a good graph: http://oi57.tinypic.com/2nqw7k9.jpg and this is a wrong graph: http://oi61.tinypic.com/2a9savc.jpg
I do not need it, but I have got this advice, that it can solve the problem. Poisson's method seems much more easier, but the above described problem seems hard.

Comment: Ok, so you are looking for "connected graphs" (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConnectedGraph.html). Now the second question what does "random" mean for you? What should be the distribution of the generated graphs?

Comment: Random means in my oppinion, that nodes are in random positions and are randomly connected with each other.

Comment: I think, that this check should be maybe in paint().